# Я хочу записать текст в файл и отобразить, но почему-то записанный текст не выводится

Tags: python-3.x, файлы

```
f = open('new', 'r+', encoding='utf-8')

f.write('Строка 1\n')
f.write('Строка 2\n')
f.write('Строка номер 3\n')
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

Пробовал и 'w+', все-равно точно не могу понять в чем тут дело.
Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело тут в том, что после записи курсор находится в конце файла и f.read() ничего не считывает, т.к. чтение ведется с того места, на котором находится курсор. Нужно или закрыть файл и снова открыть или перевести курсор в начало ( `f.seek(0)` ).